# Запрос к MSysObjects через OleDb выдает ошибку

Tags: c#, .net, access, ado.net, oledb

Делаю запрос выборки к MSysObjects из кода и в ответ получаю сообщение о том, что у меня отсутствуют права.

Как я могу обойти это проблему?

MSysObjects я хочу использовать для получения списка таблиц, которые не скрыты, так как `GetOleDbSchemaTable` возвращает мне так же скрытые таблицы, которые мне не нужны...

Попробовал GRANT на MSysObjects, но при выполнении GRANT вылетает ругань, что отсутсвует доступ к системной таблице или что-то в этом роде...

Comment: ACCDB или MDB?.